# Node.js '[object File]' BLOB

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to obtain a BLOB from a request. The request object is constructed using FormData in Angular.

`const buffer = fs.readFileSync(fileFromRequest);`

The code above returns an error:

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '[object File]'`

I can't find any resource to read/parse [object File].

Hope you guys can help me on this. Many thanks!

Comment: Do you want to upload a file?

Comment: bro `fs.readFileSync`  this will look for a file at that path

Comment: I want to get the uploaded file's extension & size from Angular. But when I receive the request object in my node app, it's of type [object File]

Comment: So you are trying to upload file from angular to node js ?

Comment: You can use Multer https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer for uploading the file to the nodejs app.

Comment: @JamesRudolf can you also vote up my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When upload a file using angular to node.js you cant use this

```
const buffer = fs.readFileSync(fileFromRequest);
```

The `fs` module only use to read to local file from the server. To handle upload data you can use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)